# Difference between QSocketNotifier::activated and QIODevice::readyRead

Tags: qt, network-programming, qt4, qsslsocket, qiodevice

I create a new Read `QSocketNotifier` (`QSocketNotifier::Read`) and I install it on a `QSslSocket`.
What is the `QSslSocket` signal that is emitted when `activated` signal is emitted from `QSocketNotifier`?

Is there any difference between the `activated` signal emitted by a `QSocketNotifier` which is installed on a `QSslSocket` and `QIODevice::readyRead` signal emitted by a `QSslSocket`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `QSocketNotifier` is watching a QIODevice, then there is no functional difference between `QIODevice::readyRead()` and `QSocketNotifier::activated(QSocketNotifier::Read)`. For that reason, you don't need a `QSocketNotifier` if you're only using `QIODevice` objects.

The main use of `QSocketNotifier` is to monitor a socket (or any other file descriptor) that you opened through a low-level API. You may pass it a file descriptor that is not associated to another QObject (such as a file opened through std::ifstream) and it will fire a `activated()` signal when you may read from your file descriptor, which is useful since a generic file descriptor won't fire Qt signals by itself.